# How can I put a name to a location

Tags: android, eclipse, gps, location

I have this code to show my location to another location but it's not the issue, how can I add a name for it?

```
locationname.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "37.967775, 23.720689";    
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                    Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                            + "&daddr=" + DESTINATION_LOCATION)); 
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

I have this:

```
String DESTINATION_LOCATION = "My location name";
```

But it doesn't fit in the code!
Does anybody know?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will open with default map and adds marker with name

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("geo:<lat>,<long>?q=<lat>,<long>(Label+Name)"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Option 2

```
String urlAddress = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q="+ myLatitude  +"," + myLongitude +"("+ labelLocation + ")&iwloc=A&hl=es";     
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(urlAddress);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: But, I don't know where to put the "name" of the location!

Comment: labelLocation itself is your location name

Comment: Thank you :) .. The "Label+Name" .. does the label means the marker?